# Alamofire - Invalid value around character 0

Tags: php, json, swift, alamofire

I am getting below error by using Alamofire. Wondering what is wrong with my server code. If I use responseString, I get a result showing the whole php code including `<?php` and `?>`. Any suggestions?

```
Alamofire.request("http://domain/test.php", method: .post, parameters: [:], encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: [:]).responseJSON { (response) in
            switch response.result {
            case .success(_):
                print(response.result.value)
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error)
            }
        }
```

Error

```
responseSerializationFailed(Alamofire.AFError.ResponseSerializationFailureReason.jsonSerializationFailed(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around character 0." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 0.}))
```

Server Code (test.php)

```
<?php

$essay = 
array(
    array("Intro" => 
        array("intro")
        ),
    array("section" => 
        array("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g" )
        ),
    array("End" => 
        array("a", "b")
        )
    );

echo json_encode($essay);

?>
```

If I use responseString, I get

```
Optional("<?php\n\n$essay = \narray(\n\tarray(\"Intro\" => \n\t\tarray(\n\t\t\t\"intro\"\n\t\t\t)\n\t\t),\n\tarray(\"1\" => \n\t\tarray(\n\t\t\t\"a\",\n\t\t\t\"b\",\n\t\t\t\"c\",\n\t\t\t\"d\",\n\t\t\t\"e\",\n\t\t\t\"f\",\n\t\t\t\"g\"\n\t\t\t)\n\t\t),\n\tarray(\"End\" => \n\t\tarray(\t\n\t\t\t\"a\", \n\t\t\t\"b\"\n\t\t\t)\n\t\t)\n\n\t);\n\necho json_encode($essay);\n\n?>\n")
```

If I try to run the code in my server, I get

```
php test.php 

[{"Intro":["intro"]},{"1":["a","b","c","d","e","f","g"]},{"End":["a","b"]}]
```

Comment: It seems like your issue is clearly with the PHP code and not the Swift one, so I'd suggest editing your question to only include the relevant code and tags. I'm not familiar with PHP, but by looking at the code I can't see any code where you'd actually send that JSON as a network request response.

Comment: @DávidPásztor `echo json_encode($essay);`...

Comment: Your server return html.

Comment: @SalmanGhumsani Any idea why return html?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus my post shows my server code which help to debug. Should not be considered as duplicate

Comment: @PakHoCheung So you have tried `responseString` instead of `responseJSON`?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus yes. it returns my whole php file code from ```<?php``` to ```?>```

Comment: @PakHoCheung That's not good, so if you visit `http://domain/test.php` using a web browser then you see the tags? This means the web server is misconfigured and serving the entire file instead of running it through the PHP interpreter.

Comment: The alamofire is expecting something like `[{"Intro":["intro"]},{"section":["a","b","c","d","e","f","g"]},{"End":["a","b"]}]` but the server is sending the file instead of JSON so it's definitely misconfigured.

Comment: Right. I visited ```http://domain/test.php``` in browser, Chrome download the file instead of execute it

Comment: @PakHoCheung Right, so the server is not configured properly. Do you have control over the server? Is it Apache, IIS, NGINX, or something else?

Comment: Er. Thanks a lot. Let me double check my PHP interpreter. Yes. I do have control over the server

Comment: You're welcome and good luck

Comment: Apache (check by ```curl -I domain```)

Comment: Thanks. Guess the reason is I zip a whole directory in local, then send it and unzip it in server. The php code is inside the directory. I tried to mkdir a directory in server and put the php code in it. It works perfect. Wondering why it doesn't work inside the unzipped directory